# Angular Material mat-table filter on multiple columns

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Im trying to add a filter to my table.

Here is the [live demo](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/Angular/angular-material-table-custom-filters-for-multiple-specific-column/) of the table with the filter. However, the filters do not narrow down. For example if I apply the ID filter of 3 and status of active. It should only display 1 results as there is only 1 user with ID of 1 and status of Active. Instead, it will display all the users with ID of 3 and also all all the users with status of active.

Is there are modifications I can do to this createFilter to output the desired result?

```
  // Custom filter method fot Angular Material Datatable
  createFilter() {
    let filterFunction = function (data: any, filter: string): boolean {
      let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
      let isFilterSet = false;
      for (const col in searchTerms) {
        if (searchTerms[col].toString() !== '') {
          isFilterSet = true;
        } else {
          delete searchTerms[col];
        }
      }

      console.log(searchTerms);

      let nameSearch = () => {
        let found = false;
        if (isFilterSet) {
          for (const col in searchTerms) {
            searchTerms[col].trim().toLowerCase().split(' ').forEach(word => {
              if (data[col].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1 && isFilterSet) {
                found = true
              }
            });
          }
          return found
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return nameSearch()
    }
    return filterFunction
  }
```

Here is the [tutorial](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-table-custom-filter-using-select-box/) I followed and the [source code](https://github.com/ipsjolly/FreakyJolly.com/tree/master/Demo/Angular/ng-material-table-multi-filter-demo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`found` will be true when one of `searchTerms` matches. If you want to return true only when all the `searchTerms` match, you should do like this.

```
if (isFilterSet) {
  for (const col in searchTerms) {
    if (searchTerms[col].toString() === '') {
      continue;
    } else {
      let found = false;
      searchTerms[col].trim().toLowerCase().split(' ').forEach(word => {
        if (data[col].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1 && isFilterSet) {
          found = true
        }
      });
      if (!found) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
} else {
  return true;
}
```